# G acts on, why is $|x^G|=|G:G_x|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

My idea is $\phi:G\to x^G$ with $\phi(g)=gx$ is a surjective homomorphism hence $|x^G|=\dfrac{|G|}{|G_x|}$ ...

Comment: You are missing an explanation as to why the stuff you wrote before the word "hence" implies the equation you wrote after the word "hence."

Answer (score 1):

If a finite group $G$ acts on a set $X$, then $\forall x \in X$, there is a bijection between $G/G_x$ and $x^G$. In particular, $\lvert G/G_x \rvert = \lvert G : G_x \rvert = \lvert x^G \rvert$. Notice that $G/G_x$ and $x^G$ are sets and not necessarly groups (so your $\phi$ is generally not an homomorphism). This is called the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem.

The bijection is given quite naturally by : 
$$\psi : G/G_x \rightarrow x^G$$
$$gG_x \mapsto g.x$$

You can show it is well-defined (i.e. it doesn't depend on the representative of the class, i.e. if $gG_x = hG_x$, then $\psi(gG_x) = \psi(hG_x)$) and bijective. But again, this is not a group isomorphism because $G/G_x$ and $x^G$ are usually sets.